# Chat markdown in comments doesn't work

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, formatting

According to [this help about comment formatting](https://iot.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), the [chat] markdown should create a link to the site chat. While the name expansion worked, the link leads to the rather general chat.stackexchange.com instead of our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49682/chat-of-things).

[Happened on this comment](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/567/knx-ip-gateways-with-support-for-knx-web-services#comment816_567)

Comment: Funny, the chat link in the comment you linked links me to the mechanics.SE chats.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/336144):

> `[chat]` – link to the current site's chat site (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ for SO, http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ for Meta SE, http://chat.stackexchange.com/ everywhere else, that last one showing a list of active rooms from the referring site), the link text being "{site name} Chat".

There is a feature request to allow behaviour more like what you suggest ([Be able to specify a particular room in the chat magic link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217006/336144) on Meta.SE) and a [similar question on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280609/the-chat-shortcut-in-comments-links-to-all-rooms-instead-of-the-main-site-room?noredirect=1&lq=1) about this behaviour in particular.

Comment: It's a strange design